# How to present NSWindow without title bar while keeping the system buttons

Tags: nswindow, titlebar

How can one remove the title bar from a NSWindow while keeping the system buttons such as close, minimize and maximize?

How to make the Window slightly transparent?

This is the look & feel that I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve the desired design:

- In the storyboard, set NSWindow's `Full Size Content View` property to `true`
- Via code, set NSWindow's `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property to `true`